# Modifying the value of an exported variable within a module doesn't change it within other modules

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a setup similar to this:

I have 3 modules: **a**, **b**, and **x**

---

**x** is a module that's exporting different variables and functions to both **a** and **b**. It looks something like this:

```
function setData(key, newValue)
{
    module.exports.data[key] = newValue
}

module.exports = {
     data: {
         name: "Jack",
         age: 24,
         preferences: gaming
     }
     funcs: {
         setData: setData
     }
}
```

**a** and **b** both import **x**, both looking something like this:

```
import things from './x.js';
```

---

I'm trying to modify the exported values in lets say module **a** for example, and have those changes reflect in **b**. I've tried something like:

```
things.data.name = "John"
```

and

```
things.funcs.setData("name", "John")
```

...and yet, whilst the value does change for **a**, these changes are NOT reflected in **b** at all. What's more unusual to me is that through using 'console.log', the changes are made in **x** when debugging **a**, but are NOT changed when debugging **b**

I've heard that using import passes modules by reference, so if that's the case then why are these changes not being reflected? Generally I'm trying to achieve something similar to global variables. Am I missing something here?

---

P.S: I'm trying to build a Chrome Extension. Maybe that's why it's not working in, maybe not, I don't really know for now

Comment: Your scripts probably run in different environments because extensions often have 3 or more: the content script in the default isolated world, the page scripts in the "main" world, the popup page, the background script/worker, the options page, etc.

Comment: Does that mean that this and any other method that tries to synchronize variables is futile (apart from maybe using the storage to save and load info)? Since the scripts run in different environments, achieving a single reference to a 'shared' variable won't work at all through the scripts themselves at least?

Comment: Only chrome-extension:// pages (not a service worker though) can access each other's globals in their `window` via chrome.extension.getViews(). For other types of contexts people typically use `chrome` messaging.